# Modx - ссылка на ресурс

Tags: php, cms, modx

Есть страница на которой много картинок-ссылок с названием товара. Каждая эта картинка идет отдельным ресурсом с доп. полями и выводятся на странице через `pdoResources`.

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при клике на каждую картинку открывалась соответствующая карточка товара, которая тоже идет отдельным ресурсом каждая и должна редактироваться через доп. поля.

Как это реализовать?

Вот контент, где должны выводиться картинки:

```
<div class="inventory-content">
    <div class="row">
        [[$inventory-menu]]
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="inventory-content-item__title_wrapper">
                <h1 class="inventory-content-item__title">Ножи пасечные</h1>
                <span class="refinement">Цены в карточках товара указаны в розницу. Если вас интересует оптовая цена, перейдите в раздел " Оптовикам"!</span> 
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="inventory-content-item">
                    [[pdoResources?
                        &parents=`64`
                        &depth=`0`
                        &tpl=`previews-item-tpl`
                        &includeTVs=`previews-img`
                    ]]
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Вот чанк каждой картинки. Он идет шаблоном для каждого ресурса с картинкой ссылкой:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="inventory-item">
    <div class="inventory-item-img">
        <a href=""><img src="[[+tv.previews-img]]" alt="" class = "inventory-item__img"></a>
        <p class="inventory-item-hover__text">Перейти к карточке товара</p> 
    </div>
    <div class="inventory-item-text">
        <span class = "inventory-item-text__title">[[+longtitle]]</span> <br>
        <span class = "inventory-item-text__price">[[+description]]</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Вот дерево ресурсов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

А зачем вам отдельные ресурсы для превью и карточки товара? Не легче сделать превью из карточки товара, тогда вам сразу будет доступен `id` ресурса и вы сможете поместить ссылку на страницу товара в ссылке-картинке.

```
<div class="inventory-content">
<div class="row">
    [[$inventory-menu]]
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="inventory-content-item__title_wrapper">
            <h1 class="inventory-content-item__title">Ножи пасечные</h1>
            <span class="refinement">Цены в карточках товара указаны в розницу. Если вас интересует оптовая цена, перейдите в раздел " Оптовикам"!</span> 
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="inventory-content-item">
                [[pdoResources?
                    &parents=`45`
                    &depth=`0`
                    &tpl=`previews-item-tpl`
                    &includeTVs=`previews-img`
                ]]
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="inventory-item">
<div class="inventory-item-img">
    <a href="[[~[[+id]]]]"><img src="[[+tv.previews-img]]" alt="" class = "inventory-item__img"></a>
    <p class="inventory-item-hover__text">Перейти к карточке товара</p> 
</div>
<div class="inventory-item-text">
    <span class = "inventory-item-text__title">[[+longtitle]]</span> <br>
    <span class = "inventory-item-text__price">[[+description]]</span>
</div>
```

Если все таки нужен отдельные ресурсы для превью и карточки товара, создайте дополнительный TV параметр у превью и запишите туда id карточки товара. Таким образом вы свяжите 2 отдельных ресурса.